# Artifactory CLI sort and limit the number of artifacts

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is there any way to sort and limit the number of artifacts while downloading artifacts using [CLI for Jfrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory)?

Example: if we have 100 artifacts in a single repo and I want to download only top 5 artifacts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jfrog CLI currently does not support SORT and LIMIT.
This is actually a roadmap item currently evaluated for Q4 17.

You can follow [this](https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/56) Github issue to stay up-to-date with the implementation efforts.

for the meantime, you can use AQL with SORT and LIMIT over the JFrog [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-Sorting).

For example, the below AQL query Sorts by Descending creation dates and Limits the returned number of items to 5.
it can be used as the body of a simple POST method:

```
items.find(
{
            "repo":"my-repo-local"
    }
).sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(5)
```

HTH,

Or

Answer (score 0):

You can not limit the download to X number of artifacts using Jfrog Cli but there are 3 ways to "limit" your artifact donwload using Jfrog Cli.

These options are:

1. If you need only a specift artifact:

   ```
   jfrog rt dl your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-NAME.EXTENSION
   ```

   This example download the artifact named YOUR-ARTIFACT-NAME.EXTENSION from "your-artifactory-local-repo" to your local folder.
2. If you need all the artifact in a folder:

   ```
   jfrog rt dl your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-FOLDER/ YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/
   ```

   This example download all the artifacts from "your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-FOLDER/" to YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/
3. Using a regular expresion (best way):

Example 3.1:

```
    jfrog rt dl "your-artifactory-local-repo/*" YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/

    This command also download all the artifacts from "your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-FOLDER/" to YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/
```

Example 3.2:

```
    jfrog rt dl "your-artifactory-local-repo/*.EXTENSION" YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/

    This command also download all the .EXTENSION from "your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-FOLDER/" to YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/
```

Example 3.3:

```
    jfrog rt dl "your-artifactory-local-repo/*SUBNAME.*" YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/

    This command also download all the artifacts that ends with "SUBANME.*" from "your-artifactory-local-repo/YOUR-ARTIFACT-FOLDER/" to YOUR-LOCAL-FOLDER/
```

The best way is using regular expressions.

Comment: these scripts can download either single file or list of files. but how can we limit the artifacts? eg: if we have 100 artifacts in a single repo and I want to download only top 5 artifacts then we should sort the artifacts and limit to 5 artifacts.

Comment: You can not limit the download to X number of artifacts using Jfrog Cli.

Answer (score 0):

this is now supported by the jfrog CLI

`jf rt search "images-docker/" --sort-by size --sort-order desc --limit 100`

it can take a while to sort when there are a lot of packages.